# Dax for % of columntotal

Tags: percentage, dax, measure

I've got a tablereport with on the rows product category and on the columns years. In the valuesection, I want to show the number of sales. This works fine. But now I also want to show the % of columntotal for the product categories.
I use dax:

```
Measure := count(factSales[salesnr])/calculate(count(factSales[salesnr]);all(factSales))
```

But this yields the percentage of grand total over all years. I want the percentage of columntotal for every seperate year.

Answer (score 0):

The `ALL(Table)` function tells Power Pivot to ignore any filters applied over the whole table. Therefore, you're telling Power Pivot to count all the rows of the *factsales* table regarless of the Category or Year being filtered on the pivot table.

However, in your case, what you want is the sum for ALL the categories on each year. Since you want the sum of ALL the categories you must use `ALL(factsales[categories]). In this way, you're ignoring only the filters for the categories and not the filters for the years.

Based on the previous explanation the dax formula would be:

```
Measure := 
    count(factSales[salesnr]) / calculate(count(factSales[salesnr]);all(factsales[categories]))
```

Comment: Yes year is on the factsales table, so i have used your second measure and you know what happined? I got the % of row total. So i changed your code into: measure:=count(factSales[salesnr])/calculate(count(factSales[salesnr];all(factSales(productcategory)). And voila i got the %of columntotal, but why this worked i dont know. If someone can explain step by step how to interpret this dax please do help me.

Comment: Oh! You're right!! I understood the problem in the other way around.

I'll edit my answer and include an explanation of why it works.

Comment: So ALL(Table) drops all the filters in my report and ALL(Table(column1)) drops all the filters except the filter applied by column1. Ok that sounds logical. Sometimes i see people resolve this problem with sumx ? What is the difference with the sumx approach.

Comment: No i said it wrong. ALL(Table(column1)) means drop only the filter on column1 and all the other filters remain?

Comment: ALL(Table) -> Drops all filters on all the columns of Table;
ALL(Table[Column1]) -> Drops all filters applied to Column1;
ALLEXCEPT(Table[Column1]) -> Drops all filters on all columns of Table except the filters applied to Column1